# Сдвинуть значения ячеек в столбце на одну позицию вверх?

Tags: excel, vba, office, excel-формулы

Как сдвинуть все значения в столбце B на одну позицию вверх, кроме первой строки разумеется? Допустим значение стоит на b2, сдвинуть его на b1 и так все значения в столбце, сортировка не подходит, важен порядок следования значений (числа) да и данные из столбца подключаются из текстового файла.

Comment: Тупо удалить B1 со сдвигом вверх. Или Cut-Paste.

Comment: Копировать диапазон, вставить на строку выше, удалить нижнее знчение. Вы бы пример показали. Возможно, есть какие-то ограничения. Обязательно макросом? Не стесняйтесь описыватьзадачу полнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определяем последнюю заполненную ячейку столбца *B* и переносим диапазон значений на строку выше:

```
Sub DataUp()
Dim lRw As Long
    lRw = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRw < 2 Then Exit Sub

    Range("B2:B" & lRw).Copy Range("B1:B" & lRw - 1)
    Range("B" & lRw).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Если допустимо *вырезать/вставить*, две строки можно заменить на

```
Range("B2:B" & lRw).Cut Range("B1:B" & lRw - 1)
```